# Single threaded future/promises in D?

Tags: d

I see that D has futures, and can create threads but is there anything like "Dart" futures/promises (or I guess javascript if you use a library)?

I want to be able to write code like this -

```
//
// NOT D code because I can't remember all the syntax!
//
auto fut = myfile.read();

fut.then(function(data) { 
    // Process data asynchronously when the future completes
};
```

I want the callback on the same thread as the main code though. This will presumably need some kind of even queue and event dispatching.
I think that ASIO in boost provides some similar facilities for C++ but something with a better syntax would be nice.

Is there anything like this in core D, or any simple way to achieve single threaded futures for async code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at vibe.d: http://vibed.org/
It enables you to write performant event driven code like you know from nodejs but in a synchronous manner using D's fibers: http://dlang.org/phobos/core_thread.html#.Fiber

Answer (score 1):

The [std.parallelism](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html) library can be used to simulate futures and promises.  I have not tried it yet, but it is documented on the page for the library as well as an [article discussing concurrency in D](http://davesdprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/7/).  It looks to be pretty easy even if it doesn't explicitly use the words "future" and "promise".